# Can an apps script macro in a Google sheet be used by other users?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a fairly simple requirement for a Google sheets apps macro script - it basically pulls the values from a couple of cells in another sheet and displays them in an alert box.

I've done the macro for this and it works fine. What I now want is for anyone I've shared the sheet with to be able to run the same macro. This is where things have suddenly got a bit more involved! My questions are:

1. Is this possible? And if so, what's the best way of achieveing it? At the moment, the macro is not available for the test user I've shared the sheet with. I've had a bit of a look around and it seems like publishing the script as a web app may be the way to go - can anyone confirm if that is correct? Or would there be a better option? I don't know anything about web apps so just want to confirm if this is the best option before trying to wrap my head around it all.
2. If the sheet in question has been shared with a user, but the second sheet which the script pulls data from has not, is it still possible for the user to run the script and retrieve the data? Or would the second sheet need to be shared with that same user as well? (If it would then it kinda defeats the object of what I'm trying to achieve).
3. Finally, would the user with whom the sheet is shared have to have a Google account in order to do this? I'm assuming so...which is a bit of a pain, but I guess understandable.

Thanks very much

Comment: Hi ! By ```sheet 1``` and ```sheet 2``` do you mean different sheets or different **Spreadsheets**? Also, is your [script bounded](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) to the Spreadsheet? What is your intention, to let users run a function from the script in your Spreadsheets right? How are you sharing your Spreadsheet (editor, viewer access, etc). Imagining your case scenario, it might be best for you if you assign a function to a button in the Spreadsheet that runs the script when the user clicks it.

Comment: Thanks Mateo...appreciate the input. Sorry, yes I should have been clearer - I'm talking about two different spreadsheets, not two different sheets within the same spreadsheet. Yes, the script is bound to the spreadsheet. I want users with whom the spreadsheet has been shared to be able to run the macro script...so yes, a button would be ideal. At the moment the spreadsheet has just been shared with a test user as a Viewer.

Comment: Hi ! In order to run your function they must have editor level access, same applies to acting a button that triggers the function, they should have editor level access to trigger the script. You could either grant editor level access to the Spreadsheet or create a separate script (or even a web app they can access) and grant access to it. What level of permissions do you want to grant the user? Would it be ok for them to have editor access to the Spreadsheet?

Comment: No, I don't want to grant users edit access (had issues in the past with people accidentally changing/deleting data when given edit access!). I've been looking at web apps and that may be a better option as I believe the app could run as me even when initiated by someone else? Can a web app be set up so that it runs from within the spreadsheet? Or would it have to run separate to it and then pull the required information from it?

Answer (score 0):

## Wokaround

> Following the requirements you have described I get that you want your users to trigger an [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) function that will alter or get data from your Spreadsheet while only granting your users viewer-only acccess.

As described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#access_to_bound_scripts) only users with editor level access can run functions on your bounded script or activate it when clicking a button in your Spreadsheet.

To overcome this you can create a simple web app with a button that will trigger your function. Users will have to access this web app to trigger the function. The good point is that they will not have editor level access to the Spreadsheet nor to the actual script of the web app (as they will just interact with its user interface).

The web app would be a different script that can interface any of your Spreadsheets editing them or getting any information from them.